# Remove 'index' from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently re-writing URL's as the following:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ articles.php?article=$2
```

This allows me to write links such as the following, depending on the currently executing page.

```
   www.example.com/blog/new-article
   www.example.com/gallery/new-gallery
```

So therefore this also results in the following, when executed on the homepage:

```
   www.example.com/index/new-post
```

I would like it so that only the URLs with 'index' in them, get rewritten without it, such as:

```
  www.example.com/index/new-post -> www.example.com/new-post
```

Can this be done? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Do you want the user to type `www.example.com/new-post` and the server to internally modify the URL to `www.example.com/index/new-post`, or the opposite ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this before your other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: i've made it the first rule, it doesn't work though, it results in a 404 not found

Comment: would it be something like: RewriteCond $1 ^(index) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ articles.php?article=$1 [L]