# Rewriting a Word in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble remove a word from a URL

I want to remove the word 'index' from a URL, I just don't know the code to do it.

I was thinking something like the following:

```
RewriteRule www.example.com/$ www.example.com/index/$1
```

Sorry I can't really do much more.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove 'index' from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693462/remove-index-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using apache.

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index[\/]*$
RewriteRule (.*)$ / [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This is the code I currently have: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ articles.php?article=$2, i just need the first variable to be removed if it's index. any ideas?